# Error when I run sudo apt-get update - have disco on bionic system

Tags: 18.04, apt, xubuntu, software-sources

```
sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'u/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'u' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main multiverse u
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *Your issue is the disco files; Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL thus the error*

Comment: If your system was bionic; you should use `ubuntu-support-status` to ensure your system remains that, and look at how much of it was upgraded to the now EOL 19.04 release ... If you didn't *pin* packages etc.. you've potentially changed your system into a 19.04 or EOL one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename *disco* (19.04, EOL) entry to correct supported *bionic* (18.04 LTS, supported until 2023 free).
Open terminal and execute:

```
sudo sed -i "s/disco/bionic/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then fix corrupted line with *`main multiverse u`* by

```
sudo sed -i "s/main multiverse u$/main multiverse universe restricted/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then run `sudo apt-get update` again.

The next recommended step is to install all upgrades with newest dependencies by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` .

---

Good resource to read - `man sources.list` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/sources.list.5.html).

Comment: thanks it's work. @N0rbert